# How can I get a word before last word using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Examples:

```
var string = "test1, test2, test3, test4, **test5**, test6"
```

**Output:
test5**

```
var string = "test5, test2, **test4**, test7
```

**Output:
test4**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<script>
var string = "test1, test2, test3, test4, test5, test6"
var value = string.split(", ").slice(-2, -1)[0] // returns "test5"
console.log( value );
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var string = "test1, test2, test3, test4, test5, test6";
var arryOfString= string.split(',');
console.log(arryOfString[arryOfString.length - 2].trim());
```

Hope this would help

Comment: You actually get `" test5"`, not `"test5"`. Adding `.trim()` to value would fix that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below code

```html
<script>
var string = "test1, test2, test3, test4, test5, test6"
var stringSplit = string.split(",");

var value = stringSplit[(stringSplit.length)-2].trim();
console.log(value);
</script>
```

Comment: You actually get `" test5"`, not `"test5"`. Adding `.trim()` to value would fix that.

Comment: @lucas I have added the `trim()` function to the result now. Thank You. upvote your answer as well :)